# How to build a modal dialog link in a calculated column to use modal dialog

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column

I have tried appending a hyperlink in a calculated column that should popup a modal dialog
but it's not working for me.

Anyone got this working?

Answer (score 1):

I find that calculated columns are not suitable for complex html, especially links that involve javascript, which the modal dialog does.

For these situations I create a DVWP in SharePoint Designer instead of a list view and build the call to the modal dialog in the DVWP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I didnt want to use DVWP.Do you think Jquery could help with the solution and list view?

Comment: You would need to use Javascript syntax to create a string that uses Javascript syntax. Possible, but challenging. How good are your Javascript skills?